# I cannot deploy static site to Netlify

Tags: html, deployment, netlify

I am trying to deploy some ui components on Netlify. However, it is not recognizing my index.html files inside the subfolders. Hence nothing is showing up on my deployed site. Also, all 3 index files have links to each other. This is my file structure

```
├── ui-components
    ├── blog-cards
    │    └── index.html
    ├── login
    │    └── index.html
    ├── ads-manager
    │    └── index.html
```

Do I have to delete my subfolders and bring out my index files for it to deploy on Netlify or is there any way around it?

**Edit:**

I made some progress by doing this instead by putting a `_redirects` file in the root of my app as suggested

```
/        /blog-cards/index.html    200
/login   /login/index.html         200
/ads-manager     /ads-manager/index.html   200
```

It's finding my index.html inside the blog-cards folder however it's not loading my css file now. Full folder structure

```
├── ui-components
    ├── blog-cards
    │    └── index.html
    │    └── style.css
    │    └── images
```

Here's a link to the [netlify site](https://infallible-kowalevski-396899.netlify.app/)

Comment: you have a main index.html? if you do and still doesn't work try to rename all that index.html in subfolders with another name but not the same.

Comment: The only thing I have inside ui-components folder is the 3 subfolders that I listed above. Inside the subfolders, I also tried changing the file names to index.html, login.html and ads.html, it still doesn't work

Comment: I think you should have one main index file, try to make a test, first add a index.html file inside ui components, next put in there 3 `<a>` tags with href to each sub html file and try to see if it works.

Comment: I mean that would definitely work. I was looking for how to make it work with subfolders. I don't want to break my subfolders because these are 3 different projects and I want to keep them organized inside the subfolders. If that makes sense.

Comment: I think this is not possible with netlify or other free hosting website.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a main `index.html` file, which is why nothing is showing up on your deployed site. You should add something there, even just a blank page or a placeholder with links to the other projects.

You probably don't have to though, just browse to `<siteurl>/ui-components/blog-cards` and that should work.

---

Update after further comments.

If there is a subfolder you want the site to automatically go to upon landing, then you can use [Redirects.](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/redirect-options/)
For example, putting the below in a file called `_redirects` in the root of your app will do what I think you need:

```
/        /ui-components/blog-cards    200
/login   /ui-components/login         200
/ads     /ui-components/ads-manager   200
```

(the 200 status code means that it will be a redirect under-the-hood, which makes the URL stay clean as you have said.)

---

**Update**

Yeah, so the forwarding is making the .css files to fail to load.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`  will look at the current URL and add `style.css` to it, which is obviously not what you want.

You could change to forwarding it with a 302, which would mean the new (not nice) URL would show up, but then the css path would resolve correctly.

Alternatively, you could add a second stylesheet link that looks for `./blog-cards/style.css`.

Or if the css is small enough you could inline it, making it all simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I end up taking out the index.html file from the blog-cards folder and completely got rid of that folder. From there I linked it to my other 2 folders. But I haven't tried the ```<siteurl>/ui-components/blog-cards``` trick. Looks like that will work too, maybe I will try that next time.

Comment: So where were you browsing to before? just the root URL of the project and expecting to be forwarded into one of the sub-folders?

Comment: Well I wasn't expecting it to straight go to one of the subfolders and find the index.html, that's why I asked the question if it's possible to do. My ideal solution would had been somehow tell netlify where my starting index.html is so that way I keep my subfolders and also keep the website url clean without <siteurl>/ui-components/blog-cards. But I guess there's no way to manually set the starting file.

Comment: Ahh right ok yeah that is possible!! Use Redirects, I've extended my answer

Comment: Send me a link to the repo and I'll have a look?

Comment: Sadly it's not a repo, I am using the folder drag and drop thing